# CRON job not setting up on linux

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I have setup the corn command using **`crontab -e`** command.

```
MAILTO=""
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.2 /var/www/vhosts/hostname/httpdocs/bin/magento cron:run --group="test"
```

I have created module to run CRON job automatically. But it is not working automatically.

Instead when I hit command '**`php bin/magento cron:run`**' it works. I am surprised CRON task is performing manually but not automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. It is working fine now.
The actual issue was with the user setting up the CRON job. I was setting the CRON job with root user. Later I set up the same CRON using developer user having ftp access and it worked perfectly.